# bash variable in json format

Tags: json, linux

How to use variables in json file

```
[root@ip-10-0-5-50 ~]# IP=`aws waf-regional list-ip-sets | grep IPSetId | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed s/,//g`
[root@ip-10-0-5-50 ~]# echo $IP
"9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95"
```

Below code executed from from script

```
ip=`aws waf-regional list-ip-sets | grep IPSetId | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed s/,//g`
echo $ip
rule_id=`aws waf-regional list-rules | grep RuleId | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed "s/\"//g"`
change_token=`aws waf-regional get-change-token | grep ChangeToken | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | sed "s/\"//g" `

aws waf-regional update-rule --rule-id $rule_id --change-token $change_token --updates '{ "Action": "INSERT","Predicate":{ "Negated":false,"Type":"IPMatch","DataId":"'"$ip"'"}}'
```

Output:

```
"9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95"
Error parsing parameter '--updates': Invalid JSON: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 81 (char 80)
JSON received: { "Action": "INSERT","Predicate":{ "Negated":false,"Type":"IPMatch","DataId":" "9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95" "}}
```

Issue coming because of `"DataId":" "9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95" "}}`

Comment: The command should work the same in a shell script as in an interactive shell.

Comment: What is it doing in the shell script? Try putting `set -x` at the beginning so you can see a trace of the command executions.

Comment: In simple explanation, i want "DataId": $ip output should come up as  "DataId":"9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95".

Comment: interactive shell success : aws waf-regional update-rule --rule-id 6542a20c-e12e-4a62-93a1-7501a50d97aa --change-token $change_token --updates '{ "Action": "INSERT","Predicate":{ "Negated":false,"Type":"IPMatch","DataId":"'"$ip"'"}}'
{
    "ChangeToken": "7a9ff14a-77bf-4e01-9426-0126c44314cf"
}

Comment: shell script failure : + echo '"' 9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95 '"'
" 9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95 "
+ aws waf-regional update-rule --rule-id 6542a20c-e12e-4a62-93a1-7501a50d97aa --change-token 39979684-a95f-4710-93a6-f5fdeb07a408 --updates '{ "Action": "INSERT","Predicate":{ "Negated":false,"Type":"IPMatch","DataId":" 9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95 "}}'

An error occurred (WAFNonexistentItemException) when calling the UpdateRule operation: The referenced item does not exist.

Comment: Reason for failing in shell script is $ip variable in json file giving space after and before quotes  "DataId":" 9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95 "}}'

Comment: Please edit the question, it's really hard to see the details in a comment.

Comment: If you're getting spaces there, they must be in the variable, so the problem is probably with how you're setting the `ip` variable.

Comment: Please edit the question and show a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sure, how can i use that variable in json without spaces. IP=9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95, how can i substitute this variable in  json line without spaces in string or double quotes  '{ "Action": "INSERT","Predicate":{ "Negated":false,"Type":"IPMatch","DataId": }}'

Comment: That's not valid bash syntax. Why do you have the word `variable` before the assignment?

Comment: You really have the variable hard-coded into the script, it doesn't get it from somewhere else?

Comment: please check the above again. Just made changes. IP=9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95 in json line {"DataId": $IP}

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question!!!!

Comment: Works fine here: https://ideone.com/YUh4yu

Comment: Hey Bamar, yeah its working fine for me too. Actually Variable value doesn't have double quotes, after converting variable value to double quotes its working fine. Thanks for your time. appreciate it

Comment: Works fine without double quotes, too: https://ideone.com/NSXFhh

Comment: Could you please check the question once, actually i have tried from script again but some other issue came up with "DataId" value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `$ip` contains double quotes around it, so you don't need to add them in your JSON. That's creating an extra set of quotes.

```
aws waf-regional update-rule --rule-id $rule_id --change-token $change_token --updates '{ "Action": "INSERT","Predicate":{ "Negated":false,"Type":"IPMatch","DataId":'"$ip"'}}'
```

Comment: Got it, Thank you. Sorry for not giving proper info initially

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is what you are trying to do?

```
#!/bin/bash
export ip="9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e"
eval aws waf-regional update-rule --rule-id 6542a20c-e12e-4a62-93a1-7501a50d97aa --change-token $change_token --updates \'{ \"Action\": \"INSERT\",\"Predicate\":{ \"Negated\":false,\"Type\":\"IPMatch\",\"DataId\":\"$ip\"}}\'
```

Comment: [root@ip-10-0-5-50 ~]# aws waf-regional update-rule --rule-id 6542a20c-e12e-4a62-93a1-7501a50d97aa --change-token 23875c26-7f98-4fa2-a002-99ded75c12ae --updates '{ "Action": "INSERT","Predicate":{ "Negated":false,"Type":"IPMatch","DataId":" 9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95 "}}'

An error occurred (WAFNonexistentItemException) when calling the UpdateRule operation: The referenced item does not exist.

Comment: [root@ip-10-0-5-50 ~]#  aws waf-regional update-rule --rule-id 6542a20c-e12e-4a62-93a1-7501a50d97aa --change-token 23875c26-7f98-4fa2-a002-99ded75c12ae --updates '{ "Action": "INSERT","Predicate":{ "Negated":false,"Type":"IPMatch","DataId":"9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95"}}'
{
    "ChangeToken": "23875c26-7f98-4fa2-a002-99ded75c12ae"
}

Comment: I am able to execute command when DataID value in double quotes  example : "DataId":"9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95"

Comment: if there is spaces after and before double quotes i am unable to execute   example : "DataId":" 9518adf6-c862-4208-84bf-749e3037cd95 "

Comment: @naveen - updated the above answer to escape all the quotes, see if that works for you.